# TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc does not consider DST

Tags: .net, timezone

We use TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc to convert UTC times to local time equivalents. When converting to time zone "Central America Standard Time" the result seems to not consider daylight saving time.

According to this page http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/city.html?n=24 and my customer they have daylight saving time in Austin, TX

My test code:

```
        DateTime result;
        DateTime utcTime = Convert.ToDateTime("20.04.2013 11:32:00");
        try
        {
            TimeZoneInfo sourceTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central America Standard Time");
            result = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcTime, sourceTimeZone);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            result = Convert.ToDateTime("01.01.1900 00:00:00");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine( Convert.ToString(result) );
```

It gives 20.04.2013 05:32:00 instead of 20.04.2013 06:32:00 (-5 hours offset in dst).
Is my use of the method wrong? A bug in the framework? Wrong configuration in windows?

Thanks and regards

Marc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Central America Standard Time" isn't the time zone you think it is. It's not the one for Austin, Texas - it's the one for *Central America* (Guatemala etc). If you look at the [Guatemala time zone](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone.html?n=94) (from the same site as you quoted before) you'll see it's always UTC-6, with no daylight savings.

See [this file](https://code.google.com/p/noda-time/source/browse/src/NodaTime.TzdbCompiler/Data/winmap/windowsZones-23.xml) (taken from [CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org)) for sample mappings. You want "Central Standard Time", which I would fully expect to do the right thing.

As a quick plug, if you want to use the [IANA time zone database](http://www.iana.org/time-zones) from .NET, you might want to consider using my [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) library instead.